# Derivative of the l2-norm of a multivariate complex matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, complex-numbers, normed-spaces

I have a 4x1 vector with complex elements $\mathbf{c}=\left[c_{1}, \dots, c_{N}\right]^{ T }$  and the following $\ell2$-norm function  $f(\mathbf{c}) = \|\textbf{A}.\textbf{c}\|_{2}^2 = \sum_{m=1}^{M}\left|\mathbf{a}_{m}^{H}\mathbf{c}\right|^{2}=\sum_{m=1}^{M}\mathbf{c}^{H}\mathbf{a}_{m}\mathbf{a}_{m}^{H}\mathbf{c}$ , where the elements of **c** are complex and have the form $c_i = r_i\cdot exp(j\Phi_i)$
I am trying to find the derivatives the aforementioned function given $r_i$ and $\Phi_i$

I tried this by decomposing my complex numbers and sums but it takes too long and I cannot shorten my formulas at the end. I think there is an alternative way as this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175263/gradient-and-hessian-of-general-2-norm) states but I am unable to find it. Any help or hints are much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the *real* vectors $(r,\phi)$, define the *complex* vectors $(p,c,b)$ as
$$\eqalign{
p &= \exp(j\phi) &\implies dp = j\,p\odot d\phi \cr
c &= r\odot p    &\implies dc = r\odot dp + p\odot dr \cr
b &= A^HAc \cr
}$$
where $\odot$ denotes the elementwise/Hadamard product.

Further, a colon will denote the trace/Frobenius product, i.e. 
$\,\,A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB)$

(**NB:** The exp() function is applied elementwise)

Calculate the differential of the *real* function $(f)$ in terms of the *real* variables $(r,\phi)$. 
$$\eqalign{
 f &= (Ac)^* : Ac \cr
df
 &= (Ac)^* : (A \, dc) + (Ac) : (A \, dc)^* \cr
 &= b^*:dc + b:dc^* \cr
 &= b^*:(r\odot dp + p\odot dr) + b:(r\odot dp + p\odot dr)^* \cr
 &= (r\odot b^*):dp + (r^*\odot b):dp^* + (p\odot b^*):dr + (p^*\odot b):dr^* \cr
 &= (r\odot b^*):(j\,p\odot d\phi) + (r^*\odot b):(j\,p\odot d\phi)^*
  + (p\odot b^*):dr + (p^*\odot b):dr^* \cr
 &= (j\,p)\odot(r\odot b^*):d\phi + (j\,p)^*\odot(r^*\odot b):d\phi^*
  + (p\odot b^*):dr + (p^*\odot b):dr^* \cr
 &= 2\,{\mathcal Re}(j\,p\odot r\odot b^*):d\phi + 2\,{\mathcal Re}(p\odot b^*):dr \cr
}$$
The fact that $(dr^*=dr,\,\,d\phi^*=d\phi)$ and ${\mathcal Re(z)=\tfrac{1}{2}(z+z^*)}$ allows terms to be combined in that last line.

In this form, the gradients can be identified as
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial f}{\partial\phi}
 &= 2\,{\mathcal Re}(j\,p\odot r\odot b^*) \cr
 &= 2r\odot {\mathcal Im}(p^*\odot b) \cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial r} &= 2\,{\mathcal Re}(p^*\odot b) \cr
}$$

Comment: Thank you for  your answer but what do you mean exactly by "the real and imaginary components of a variable are treated independently" and the **c** you are using here is the vector, I assume? or is it an element of the vector? And how is the $\mathbf{c}*$ relevant here? Anyway my variables are $r_i$ & $\Phi_i$  so my derivatives are $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \Phi_i}$ & $\frac{\partial f}{\partial r_i}$ and not $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{c}}$

Comment: Sorry. the answer has been re-worked to find the gradients with respect to $(r,\phi)$ instead of $(c,c^*)$.

Comment: Thank you so much @greg . This is exactly what I needed. Just one question: Is  the $A^{*}$ the Conjugate transpose or just the Conjugate?

Comment: In my post, the symbols  $(A^T,A^*,A^H)$ denote the $($transpose, complex conjugate, hermitian conjugate$)$ of $A$, respectively.

Comment: I figured so, but I wanted to be sure. Again thank you so much, you are a hero sir :)